# Same options with different order cause different behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I had believed that the typeset positions of `Exp1` and `Exp2` in the following code should be the same on paper. The only difference between `Exp1` and `Exp2` is the order of the options `xshift` and `scale`. But the real typeset shows that their typeset positions are not the same. Why? And is there a general rule to determine if the order of `TikZ" options should be taken into account?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\path[fill=red](current page.center)node[below left]{page center for reference} circle (0.1);

% Exp 1:
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\path(current page.center)node[xshift=2cm,scale=3]{Exp1};

% Exp 2:
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\path(current page.center)node[scale=3,xshift=2cm]{Exp2};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you say, the order of translation and scaling gets reversed. This means that you shift by "(scale factor)*(shift distance)" but in the second example the scale factor is 3, so you shift by 6cm as opposed to 1 times 2cm in the first case.

Comment: you see same with `\includegraphics`, `\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{...}` makes an image 2cm _high_  `\includegraphics[angle=90,width=2cm]{...}` makes an image 2cm _wide_

Comment: So, the oder of options is very important? I'm confused if there is a general rule to think about the effect of the options' order.

Comment: The order of transformation options count.

Comment: A (tikz coordinate) transformation is equivalent to a transformation matrix, and applying a trans-option is to multiply the corresponding matrix to the current accumulated trans-matrix. Since matrix multiplication is not commutative in general, transformations are not too. For example, `scale=3,xshift=2cm` will transform `(0,0)` to `(0,0)`, then to `(2cm,0)`, but `xshift=2cm,scale=3` will transform `(0,0)` to `(2cm,0)`, then to (6cm,0)`. Bonus: `scale=3,xshift=2cm` is equivalent to `xshift=2cm,scale around={3:(2cm,0)}`.